# How do I use the new binding in List with children with Swift 5.5?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've understood how to use the new binding feature for dynamic fields within a list.
However, when my data has children, I get an error message: ""Key path value type 'Binding<[Item]?>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Binding<[Item]>?'"

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var number: Int
    var name: String
    var children: [Item]?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedItemID: UUID?
    
    @State private var items = [
        Item(number: 3, name: "Item A"),
        Item(number: 5, name: "Folder", children:
                [Item(number: 7, name: "Item B-A"),
                 Item(number: 7, name: "Item B-B")
                ]),
        Item(number: 7, name: "Item C")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($items, id: \.id, children: \.children, selection: $selectedItemID) { $item in
                TextField("EditItem", text: $item.name)
                    .tag(item.id as UUID?)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a workaround, what about making children non-optional and default to []?

Comment: Nah, can't get it to work. And documentation says: "children: KeyPath<Data.Element, Data?>", so I guess it needs to be optional (but I'm not entirely sure)

Comment: Now I see what it is, you are mixing functionality in a way that is not supported. You can't have both `children` and row content that is a binding.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds weird that it's not possible (using swiftUI) Would I then need to turn to AppKit?

Comment: To be clear, when I said it isn’t possible I meant not with a single List since there is no such init available. There could be other ways to solve it, I haven’t tried myself so I don’t know

Comment: Good news. It seems that support of hierarchical data for Lists (and OutlineGroup) has been added in XCode 13 beta5.